# remove all attributes in php but keep href, terget, rel in link as is

Tags: php, regex, attributes, href, except

Please suggest me the **PHP regex** for **preg_replace** to remove all the attributes from tags in HTML code without removing the tags. But in hyper links all the attributes such as href, terget, rel should remain as is

Please refer the below example:

I already tried below **regex** with **preg_replace**:

```
$htmltext = '<p style="float: left;">
<span style="color: #ff0000;">
<b>Some text here</b>
</span>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://thebankexam.com/page/7017">Clickable Text</a>
</p>';
$my_output = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>',$htmltext);
echo $my_output;
```

**Filtered output ($my_output):**

```
<p>
<span>
<b>Some text here</b>
</span>
<a>Clickable Text</a>  <!-- Check this hyper link href, rel and target gone -->
</p>
```

**The intended output should look like:**

```
<p>
<span>
<b>Some text here</b>
</span>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://thebankexam.com/page/7017">Clickable Text</a>
</p>
```

Comment: yes Owen, except the clickable link attributes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I have below regex, but it removes href, rel and target as well and keeps only `<a>Clickable Text</a>` REGEX: `preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>',$htmltext)`

Comment: That has some of the most mental answers I have seen on so. Apparently this is impossible without Chuck norris

Comment: When you mention only from clickable links, does that mean you would like to remove those attributes (href, target, rel) if they are not in a clickable link?

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_replace('/<a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '<a href="\1">', $html);
```

Comment: @OwenBeresford What do you mean? I think you don't understand what my code is doing.

Comment: The task spec said remove attribs where they are *not* part of the anchors.  The OP updated the task on my first comment. 
Your regex is matching anchors only.

Comment: @Marek this won't match single quotes in case the string was `<a href='http://somedomain.com' target='_blank'>`